# How can I earn money in PGA Tour 2K21 without a Nintendo Switch account?

Tags: nintendo-switch, pga-tour-2k21

How can I earn the coins used to buy new clubs and clothing in [PGA Tour 2K21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGA_Tour_2K21)? [This reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/pga2k21/comments/igzfq1/how_to_earn_moneycoins/) suggests that you earn coins by playing career mode, but the Nintendo Switch profile I play on does not have a Nintendo Account linked, so I can't play career mode. (It's a shared account used for local multiplayer)

[This article suggests local, offline play awards money](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/how-to-earn-money-in-pga-tour-2k21) but I've played three local multiplayer rounds and earned nothing.

Is it possible to earn money in PGA Tour 2K21 without online access?